# python function output None

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
def getAnswer (answerNumber):
    if getAnswer == 1:
        return 'It is certain'
    elif getAnswer == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'  
    elif getAnswer == 3:
        return 'Yes' 
    elif getAnswer == 4:
        return "Reply hazy try again"
    elif getAnswer == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif getAnswer == 6:
        return "Concentrate and ask again"
    elif getAnswer == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif getAnswer == 8:
        return 'not so good'
    elif getAnswer == 9:
        return 'doubtful'

r = random.randint(1 , 9)
future = getAnswer(r)
print(future)
```

Comment: Add "print(answerNumber)" to the end of getAnswer, that will tell you what you've passed in.  But really you need to check the code, you are checking getAnswer when I believe you want answerNumber in the if logic.

Comment: I didn't realize i was typing getAnswer in the if logic thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
def getAnswer (answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'It is certain'
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'  
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes' 
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return "Reply hazy try again"
    elif answerNumber == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 6:
        return "Concentrate and ask again"
    elif answerNumber == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif answerNumber == 8:
        return 'not so good'
    elif answerNumber == 9:
        return 'doubtful'

r = random.randint(1 , 9)
future = getAnswer(r)
print(future)
```

you were comparing the function `getAnswer` to the integer value and since no `else` statement defined there, function call return `None`.

all i changed was to compare the actual number `answerNumber` to the number in code.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing in the random number as `answerNumber` and then checking against the value of `getAnswer`. So, the function is trying to compare a reference to a function with an integer, which will obviously never evaluate to `True`. Because none of the `if` statements evaluate to `True`, it gets to the end of your function without hitting a return statement, and so by default returns `None`.

Replace all of the `getAnswer` references in the function body with `answerNumber` and you should be all set. Something like:

```
import random
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
    if answerNumber == 1:
        return 'It is certain'
    elif answerNumber == 2:
        return 'It is decidedly so'  
    elif answerNumber == 3:
        return 'Yes' 
    elif answerNumber == 4:
        return "Reply hazy try again"
    elif answerNumber == 5:
        return 'Ask again later'
    elif answerNumber == 6:
        return "Concentrate and ask again"
    elif answerNumber == 7:
        return 'My reply is no'
    elif answerNumber == 8:
        return 'not so good'
    elif answerNumber == 9:
        return 'doubtful'

r = random.randint(1 , 9)
future = getAnswer(r)
print(future)
```